# Network tunneling using Ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I do `ssh username@myserver.com -L 3000:171.17.258.16:1500` on a Windows machine using Ruby?

On my Windows machine I am using the rye gem to do a simple connection like:

```
@rbox = Rye::Box.new(@hostname, :user => @username, :password => @password)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try checking out the Net-SSH gem?

http://rubygems.org/gems/net-ssh/

http://net-ssh.github.com/net-ssh/

Seems like the `forward` method does what you want to do:

```
Net::SSH.start("host", "user", :password => "password") do |ssh|
  ssh.forward.local(1234, "www.google.com", 80)
  ssh.loop { true }
end
```